# django wsgi urls Import error

Tags: python, django, django-forms, wsgi, django-wsgi

My Apache error msg gives the following (error should be on the last line):

```
[wsgi:error] [pid 17520] [client 192.168.0.117:56678] mod_wsgi (pid=17520): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/vhosts/questionaireapp/quest/wsgi.py'., referer: http://questionaireapp:1337/
[wsgi:error][client 192.168.0.117:56678] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://questionaireapp:1337/
[client 192.168.0.117:56678]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 187, in __call__, referer: http://questionaireapp:1337/
[wsgi:error][client 192.168.0.117:56678]     response = self.get_response(request), referer: http://questionaireapp:1337/
[wsgi:error][client 192.168.0.117:56678]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 199, in get_response, referer: http://questionaireapp:1337/
[wsgi:error][client 192.168.0.117:56678]     response = self.handle_uncaught_exception(request, resolver, sys.exc_info()), referer: http://questionaireapp:1337/
[wsgi:error][client 192.168.0.117:56678]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 239, in handle_uncaught_exception, referer: http://questionaireapp:1337/
[wsgi:error][client 192.168.0.117:56678]     if resolver.urlconf_module is None:, referer: http://questionaireapp:1337/
[wsgi:error][client 192.168.0.117:56678]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 366, in urlconf_module, referer: http://questionaireapp:1337/
[wsgi:error][client 192.168.0.117:56678]     self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name), referer: http://questionaireapp:1337/
[wsgi:error][client 192.168.0.117:56678]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module, referer: http://questionaireapp:1337/
[wsgi:error][client 192.168.0.117:56678]     __import__(name), referer: http://questionaireapp:1337/
[wsgi:error][client 192.168.0.117:56678] ImportError: No module named quest.urls, referer: http://questionaireapp:1337/
```

My wsgi.py file is:

```
 import os
 import site
 import sys


 envpath= '/var/www/vhosts/questionaireapp/env/quest/bin/python2.7/site-packages'
 pwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

 os.chdir(pwd)

 sys.path= [pwd] + sys.path

 site.addsitedir(envpath)



 #sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

 #os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "quest.settings")

 from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler

 os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'
 application = WSGIHandler()
```

My wsgi.py runs with no problems!

My urls.py is:

```
 from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
 from django.contrib import admin
 from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


 from quest import views


 urlpatterns = patterns('',
                   url(r'^usercp/', include('usercp.urls')),
                   url(r'^questionaire/', include('exams.urls')),
                   url(r'^$', views.home, name="home"),
                   url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls))
)
```

My settings.py regarding urls is:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'quest.urls'
```

All files (wsgi settings and urls are on the same folder)

My virtual host is:

```
 WSGIPythonPath /var/www/vhosts/questionaireapp/quest
 <VirtualHost *:1337>
 WSGIDaemonProcess exams python-path=/var/www/vhosts/questionaireapp:/var/www/vhosts/questionaireapp/exams/lib/python2.7/site-packages
 WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/questionaireapp/quest/wsgi.py

WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName questionaireapp
    ServerAlias *.questionaireapp
    DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/questionaireapp/
    LogLevel info

Alias /static /var/www/vhosts/questionaireapp/static

<Directory /var/www/vhosts/questionaireapp>
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: add '/var/www/vhosts/questionaireapp/' to sys.path

Comment: In wsgi.py ? Wsgi.py is fine.. or where you mean?

Comment: Add it in wsgi.py file and try